# Pronomes pessoais oblíquos e 'você'

Tags: pronomes-oblíquos, norma-culta

Acreditando as páginas da [Norma Culta](https://www.normaculta.com.br/pronomes-pessoais-obliquos/), *você* não existe como pronome pessoal oblíquo.

Na mesma página, o seguinte exemplo é dado:

> Você sabe que eu gosto de ti.

Eu achava que misturar a segunda e terceira pessoa seria condenada. Alguém pode confirmar que *ti* de fato é o pronome pessoal oblíquo correspondendo a *você*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem razão quanto ao fato de ser errado (segundo a gramática normativa) misturar pronomes de tratamento. Logo, usar ti como pronome oblíquo para você não é correto.

Em Portugal, usa-se *si* nesses casos, então esta frase provavelmente seria escrita como:

> Você sabe que eu gosto de si.

No entanto, no Brasil o uso de *si* se restringe ao modo reflexivo (por exemplo, "ela falava de si mesma"), por isso, o pronome você é usado como pronome oblíquo. Portanto, no Brasil, essa frase provavelmente seria escrita como:

> Você sabe que eu gosto de você.

---

Algumas referências:

Veja o terceiro significado da palavra si [neste dicionário português](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/si): "Refere-se à pessoa com quem se fala, geralmente num registo de língua formal." Exemplo citado: "eu espero por si".

Já [neste dicionário brasileiro](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/palavra/QwXeb/si-2/), apenas usos reflexivos são apresentados.

Comment: Tu sabes que gosto de ti.  Também no Brasil no norte e sul, né? Vocé em Portugal é formal (pessoa mais velha ou chefe,etc.)

Comment: @Lambie sim, sim, frases com pronome tu e conjugação na segunda pessoa são utilizadas ainda em alguns estados do Brasil, por exemplo, Rio Grande do Sul e Pará (este fica no norte). Acabei não falando disso porque tive a impressão de que a pergunta estava mais focada na questão "de ti" vs "de si" vs "de você". Mas muito obrigado pela observação.